# C# Project Management with Maven

Tags: c#, maven-2

Anyone had experience of managing C# based projects with Maven?

If yes , please tell me a few words about it , how weird would it be to create such a setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maven is language agnostic and it should be possible to use it with other languages than Java, including C#. For example, the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) can be configured to use the [`csharp`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html) compiler. There is also a [.NET Maven plugin](http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/mavenite/dotnet-maven-plugin/) and there was a [maven-csharp](http://maven-csharp.javaforge.com/) on javaforge.com (seems dead).

But Java is  getting most attention and man power and there is not much done with other languages. So, while using Maven with C# is in theory possible, I wouldn't expect much support and feedback from the community (i.e. in case of problem, you'll be  alone). I don't know if using Maven for C# would thus be a good idea. I wouldn't recommend it actually (I may be wrong of course).

Answer (score 21):

I work with a suite of C# and C++ components and applications that are dependency-managed via maven. The general rule of "If it can be done via command-line, it can be done in maven" holds, so we end up having a lot of .bat, .exe and powershell "glue" to get all the pieces playing together.

The biggest problem with using maven for a Microsoft stack is a complete lack of familiarity with the build/deployment/ALM cycle for ANY new developer. You can find many developers with MSBuild, TFSBuild, ANT, etc., experience, but it's a rare thing to find a C# or C++ dev who's worked with maven in a pure Microsoft shop. The rollout of maven for dependency management and build process is consequently extremely difficult, since you end up spending a LOT of time training developers (what's the difference between a snapshot and a release?), over-componentizing the product then scaling it back to get it right, etc.

I've also found that we've had to work around maven to do something resembling continuous integration and continuous delivery. About 70% of our technology stack is C# (the rest being C++), and we want to deploy most of that to QA servers every single night with the latest-and-greatest code by default. To balance the value of release builds vs. dev productivity via snapshots, we ended up constructing a build process where we create a release build of every component each night, followed by a snapshot build. This let the developers not have to worry about bumping POMs to consume snapshots in the morning. Overall, it's a royal pain, at least for someone coming from robust continuous integration, "build and deploy everything" environments.

Maven holds a lot of promise for dependency management and isolating breaking changes (particularly in interface components where the consumer and producer have to agree). Those problems have been solved other ways (svn externs, deployment builds, interface version management, etc.). But it is relatively nice to download any component, run "mvn compile", and see the code compile (assuming a basic level of build portability). For me, though, the overhead and the meta-conversations about getting the build right (as opposed to focusing on customer value) minimize the value of maven overall.

Answer (score 7):

For .NET Core, you can use the [dotnet-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kaspersorensen/dotnet-maven-plugin) which drives the `dotnet` and `nuget` commands, as well as adds support for e.g. cleaning, releasing etc. in the "Maven way".

Here's an example plugin configuration:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <packaging>dotnet</packaging>

  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eobjects.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>dotnet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.11</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

(Notice the packaging type set to dotnet).

This will then read from the project.json file and run dotnet and nuget commands according to the maven lifecycle phases such as clean, compile, test, install etc.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example

Comment: You may want to mention you wrote it.

Answer (score 4):

You might also check out [NPanday](http://npanday.codeplex.com/) (it is a project I am involved in). While it still needs some work to more closely align to Maven's best practices, it is the most complete and active alternative available now. One feature that is unique to it is the existence of a Visual Studio Add-in for generating the correct `pom.xml` from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [NMaven](http://nmaven.codeplex.com/releases/view/20214) project at codeplex but it doesn't seem to be active or popular. See also these questions:

- [maven for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392781/maven-for-net) ([DroidIn.net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135946/droidin-net)'s  link to his [tutorial](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Using+Maven+to+manage+.NET+projects) looks promising)
- [Why is there no need for maven in
  .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729545/why-is-there-no-need-for-maven-in-net)
- [Is there a Maven Alternative or port
  for the .NET world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652583/is-there-a-maven-alternative-or-port-for-the-net-world)

Answer (score 0):

maven-compiler-plugin with plexus-compiler-csharp works just fine with the following configuration. Of course you'll have to point to an actual C# compiler on your machine with the "executable" parameter.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>csharp</compilerId>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe</executable>
        <outputFileName>myDLL</outputFileName>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-csharp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://interfaceable.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-mavenize-visual-studio-project.html

At the time i developed those scripts/solution i was unaware that such csharp support existed from Maven, but i do recommend using Maven for the build since it enables you to automate/orchestrate everything such as IIS + ActiveMQ + MongoDB bring-up on the pre-integration-test phase, and then we are able to run tests using vstest. Not to mention that you can integrate it with Jenkins and run your builds on a remote machine.

I personally recommend it, but bear in mind that you will be faced with some challenges sometimes.