# Generating jar file using maven in db unit installation

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin

I need to install db unit in my system. I have completed installing JDBC driver. i have downloaded junit-4.11.jar.

I have to generate the jar file into the directory.What is the correct method/step of doing this.AS per the link:
http://www.dbunit.org/building.html

i tried to run the command `mvn` from command line.
But i get the error

```
C:\Users\suvin>mvn install
```

`[INFO] Scanning for projects...`
`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`[INFO] BUILD FAILURE`
`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`[INFO] Total time: 0.225s`
`[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 20 14:51:56 IST 2012`
`[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M`
`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\suvin). Please verify you invoked Maven from the co
rrect directory. -> [Help 1]`
`[ERROR]`
`[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.`
`[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`
`[ERROR]`
`[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

it seems `C:\Users\suvin` location doesn't have pom file, Before execute "mvn install" your command prompt should be in place where your POM file exist.

For your information.

Normaly from a source codes you can build(compile) it and get your jars. To build a source codes you can use either ant or maven which are some build tools in java. Source codes providers provide their source codes with build.xml or pom.xml or both. You could use your build technology to compile that java source and get jar from it.

you can learn [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) from the web

Comment: thanks for the reply. Where can i find the POM file. is it within the maven directory

Comment: The pom file is at the root at the folder that contains the project, and it's usually named as pom.xml

Comment: you can directly download dbunit from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbunit/files/

Comment: @DiegoPino  thanks for the reply, what kind of project do we find pom.xml file. only java projects?? can it be found in project created using visual studio/visual c#

Comment: @suvi please find my updates in answer. Also Can you locate pom.xml in your downloaded source codes

Comment: @Sura I've only used Maven with Java projects, but apparently Maven is language agnostic and it can be used to manage projects in other languages such as C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281052/c-sharp-project-management-with-maven

Comment: @DiegoPino,  could you please suggest me a good database Schema testing tool

Answer (score 0):

Is dbUnit dependency is included in the POM file, if so mvn install does what you are expecting it to do

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i have zero knowledge on dbunit and the files. so could you please explain what is this POM file. should i create one, or is it already present?