# Interface of .so with .jar

Tags: java, android, c++, maven, jar

I have pure C++ code for which I have added pom.xml file so that I can get it builded over Maven platform. After building .jar file is getting created but is empty.

What changes do I need to do in my pom.xml file so that my .jar file will have all the interfaces of .so file?

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928931/2185630). Feel free to read the entire thread though, not just this answer...